# Highcharter deprecated function's output is different than suggested

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

I am producing a time series plot with Josh Kunst's excellent `highcharter` library in R.

Using this data:

```
    > dput(t)
structure(c(2, 2, 267822980, 325286564, 66697091, 239352431, 
94380295, 1, 126621669, 158555699, 32951026, 23, 108000151, 132505189, 
29587564, 120381505, 25106680, 117506099, 22868767, 115940080, 
22878163, 119286731, 22881061), .Dim = c(23L, 1L), index = structure(c(1490990400, 
1490994000, 1490997600, 1491001200, 1491004800, 1491008400, 1491012000, 
1491026400, 1491033600, 1491037200, 1491040800, 1491058800, 1491062400, 
1491066000, 1491069600, 1491073200, 1491076800, 1491109200, 1491112800, 
1491120000, 1491123600, 1491156000, 1491159600), tzone = "US/Mountain", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "US/Mountain", tzone = "US/Mountain", .CLASS = "double", .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "count"))
```

I can make this graph

[image]

with

`highcharter::highchart() %>% hc_add_series_xts(t)`

But I get this warning:

```
'hc_add_series_xts' is deprecated.
Use 'hc_add_series' instead.
```

So, being the easy-going type, I do exactly that and with

```
highcharter::highchart() %>% hc_add_series(t)  %>% hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')
```

I make this graph:

[image]

The problem is I really like that little `dygraph`-style window and slider at the bottom of the first graph, not to mention that it orients the labels on the right y-axis, etc.

Other than "please don't deprecate that function" how can I go about making sure the second output - using the suggested and soon, it seems, only function - looks like the first?

Comment: Pls edit you question inserting the result of `dput(t)`, this is not reproducible atm

Comment: @GGamba done.  thanks for that - I will use from hereon out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph you want is of type 'stock' instead of the default 'chart' (think 'Highcharts' vs 'Highstock').

Specifying the type solve your issue:

```
highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
    hc_add_series(t) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')
```

[image]

Comment: Any advice on getting this pipe to represent a `forecast` object made with `auto.arima()`? I'm getting `Error in as.Date.ts(.) : unable to convert ts time to Date class` warnings when I use those objects for the data arg in `hc_add_series`...

Comment: Maybe, but that belongs to another question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188706/how-can-i-get-highcharter-to-represent-a-forecast-object