# How can I get highcharter to represent a forecast object?

Tags: r, highcharts, forecasting, r-highcharter

This is a follow-on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187513/highcharter-deprecated-functions-output-is-different-than-suggested/43188116#43188116).

I am trying to get the pipeline given in that question to accept a forecast object as input:

Again, using this data:

```
> dput(t)
structure(c(2, 2, 267822980, 325286564, 66697091, 239352431, 
94380295, 1, 126621669, 158555699, 32951026, 23, 108000151, 132505189, 
29587564, 120381505, 25106680, 117506099, 22868767, 115940080, 
22878163, 119286731, 22881061), .Dim = c(23L, 1L), index = structure(c(1490990400, 
1490994000, 1490997600, 1491001200, 1491004800, 1491008400, 1491012000, 
1491026400, 1491033600, 1491037200, 1491040800, 1491058800, 1491062400, 
1491066000, 1491069600, 1491073200, 1491076800, 1491109200, 1491112800, 
1491120000, 1491123600, 1491156000, 1491159600), tzone = "US/Mountain", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "US/Mountain", tzone = "US/Mountain", .CLASS = "double", .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "count"))
```

I use

```
highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
    hc_add_series(t) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')
```

To create

[image]

But if I follow this same recipe using

```
require("forecast")
t.arima <- auto.arima(t)
x <- forecast(t.arima, level = c(95, 80))

highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
     hc_add_series(x) %>%
     hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.Date.ts(.) : unable to convert ts time to Date class
```

How can I show the forecast series along with the historical?  I've seen this in the documentation, but don't understand why I'd be getting this error.

JS CONSOLE OUTPUT FOR JK:
[image]
DF DATA AFTER RE-INDEXING:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Index = structure(c(1490968800, 1490972400, 1490976000, 
1490979600, 1490983200, 1490986800, 1490990400, 1491004800, 1491012000, 
1491015600, 1491019200, 1491037200, 1491040800, 1491044400, 1491048000, 
1491051600, 1491055200, 1491087600, 1491091200, 1491098400, 1491102000, 
1491134400, 1491138000, 1491217200, 1491220800, 1491224400, 1491228000, 
1491231600, 1491235200, 1491238800, 1491242400, 1491246000, 1491249600, 
1491253200, 1491256800, 1491260400, 1491264000, 1491267600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Data = c(2, 2, 259465771, 315866206, 64582553, 233440220, 
91918347, 1, 126563786, 158555699, 32951026, 23, 108000151, 132505189, 
29587564, 120381505, 25106680, 117506099, 22868767, 115898351, 
22878163, 119285747, 22881061, 157925588, 32447780, 223096830, 
281656273, 45406684, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Fitted = c(102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Point Forecast` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 
    102170573.857143, 102170573.857143, 102170573.857143), `Lo 80` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -16003477.5789723, 
    -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723, 
    -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723, 
    -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723, -16003477.5789723), 
    `Hi 80` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 
    220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 
    220344625.293258, 220344625.293258, 220344625.293258), `Lo 95` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -78561041.5917782, 
    -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782, 
    -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782, 
    -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782, -78561041.5917782), 
    `Hi 95` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 
    282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 
    282902189.306064, 282902189.306064, 282902189.306064)), .Names = c("Index", 
"Data", "Fitted", "Point Forecast", "Lo 80", "Hi 80", "Lo 95", 
"Hi 95"), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is due to the irregular time series.

Anyway, `ggfortify:::fortify.forecast` is your friend. Why? Because `fortify` (try to) transform all the R object in data frames. So:

```
library(highcharter)
library(forecast)
t.arima <- auto.arima(t)
x <- forecast(t, level = c(95, 80))

library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggfortify'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:forecast':
#> 
#>     gglagplot
class(x)
#> [1] "forecast"

df <- fortify(x)
head(df)
#>   Index      Data    Fitted Point Forecast Lo 80 Hi 80 Lo 95 Hi 95
#> 1     1         2 140658844             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2  3601         2 121734145             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 3  7201 267822980 105355638             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 4 10801 325286564 127214522             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 5 14401  66697091 153863779             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 6 18001 239352431 142136089             NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Now you can:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(df, "line", hcaes(Index, Data), name = "Original") %>% 
  hc_add_series(df, "line", hcaes(Index, Fitted), name = "Fitted") %>%
  hc_add_series(df, "line", hcaes(Index, `Point Forecast`), name = "Forecast") %>% 
  hc_add_series(df, "arearange", hcaes(Index, low = `Lo 80`, high = `Hi 80`), name = "Interval")
```

[image]

As you can see, `fortify` can't detect the real time too. So you need to transform the Index in the time what you want.

Comment: So if I reformat the index with `df$Index <- c(zoo::index(t)+7614000, (max(zoo::index(t))+7614000+3600*1:10))` in order to line it up with `2017-03-31` and the 10h forecast front edge, and I rerun this code, the graph that comes back in blank.

Comment: Open the widget in chrome, press F12 and check the javascript console

Comment: Okay, I used `df$Index <- c(zoo::index(t), (max(zoo::index(t)) + 3600*1:10))` and I added a snap of the js console to the question. looks to be an empty `svg.highcharts-root` object.

Comment: Is it a problem with the NAs? I added the current state of `df` to the question, as well

Comment: It's not an issue with the NAs, I replaced them all with 1s and it still isn't rendering...

Comment: I've got this "sort of" working with `type = 'line'` but as you can see I lose that beautiful `arearange` geom this way :( Added to the question under "4/4 Edit"

Comment: It won' let me paste this code in there for some reason.  Try: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=pT43BsTZ&version=1

Comment: Use `datetime_to_timestamp` function, this convert R date time values to numeric date time values which highcharts can interpret `df$Index <- datetime_to_timestamp(c(zoo::index(t), (max(zoo::index(t)) + 3600*1:10)))`

Comment: `df  <- xts::as.xts(select(df, -Index), df$Index)` will no longer work with that class of Index: `Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, ...) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Error in as.Date.ts(.) : unable to convert ts time to Date class
```

is due to the fact that you have a ts object with a frequency that is not covered by the function `as.Date.ts(.)`. When we see what this function does, this is what we get:

```
function (x, offset = 0, ...) 
{
    time.x <- unclass(time(x)) + offset
    if (frequency(x) == 1) 
        as.Date(paste(time.x, 1, 1, sep = "-"))
    else if (frequency(x) == 4) 
        as.Date(paste((time.x + 0.001)%/%1, 3 * (cycle(x) - 1) + 
            1, 1, sep = "-"))
    else if (frequency(x) == 12) 
        as.Date(paste((time.x + 0.001)%/%1, cycle(x), 1, sep = "-"))
    else stop("unable to convert ts time to Date class")
}
```

This function considers only 3 values for the frequency of a ts object: 1, 4, or 12. When we take a look at the frequency of your object `x`, we see that its `frequency = 0.000277777777777778`, so when highcharter calls the function using the ts objects in `x` it stops and gives you that error.

We have two options on how to "fix" it:

1. Transform `t` into a ts object (instead of a xts object) with `frequency = 1` **before** running `auto.arima` and `forecast`;
2. **After** running `auto.arima` and `forecast`, we can create an index for the future dates and transform the ts objects in `x` into xts objects with the correct index.

I said "fix" because these solutions are not perfect, as we will see.

## Option 1

```
t <- structure(
  c(2, 2, 267822980, 325286564, 66697091, 239352431,
    94380295, 1, 126621669, 158555699, 32951026, 23, 
    108000151, 132505189, 29587564, 120381505, 25106680,
    117506099, 22868767, 115940080, 22878163, 119286731, 
    22881061), 
  .Dim = c(23L, 1L), 
  index = structure(c(1490990400, 1490994000, 1490997600, 
                      1491001200, 1491004800, 1491008400, 
                      1491012000, 1491026400, 1491033600, 
                      1491037200, 1491040800, 1491058800, 
                      1491062400, 1491066000, 1491069600, 
                      1491073200, 1491076800, 1491109200, 
                      1491112800, 1491120000, 1491123600, 
                      1491156000, 1491159600), 
                    tzone = "US/Mountain", 
                    tclass = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), 
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), 
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), 
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
  .indexTZ = "US/Mountain", 
  tzone = "US/Mountain", 
  .CLASS = "double", 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, "count"))


require("forecast")
library(highcharter)


# SOLUTION 1
t.tmp <- ts(t, start=1, end = length(t))
t.arima.1 <- auto.arima(t.tmp)
x.1 <- forecast(t.arima.1, level = c(95, 80))

highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.1) %>%
  hc_add_series(x.1$x, name = "Original") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.1$fitted, name = "Fitted")
```

[image]

The problem with this approach is that we lose the dates (axis, tooltip, etc.).

## Option 2, 1st try: Hourly Forecasts

I tried to create an hourly index for the future values, but for some reason Highcharter moves the intervals to the left (or there's some problem with the dates that I can't see/figure out).

[image]

## Option 2, 2nd try: Daily Forecasts

When I changed it to a daily index for the future values it worked, but it's weird since we have hourly observations and the forecast part of our plot shows "daily forecasts".

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
t <- structure(
  c(2, 2, 267822980, 325286564, 66697091, 239352431,
    94380295, 1, 126621669, 158555699, 32951026, 23, 
    108000151, 132505189, 29587564, 120381505, 25106680,
    117506099, 22868767, 115940080, 22878163, 119286731, 
    22881061), 
  .Dim = c(23L, 1L), 
  index = structure(c(1490990400, 1490994000, 1490997600, 
                      1491001200, 1491004800, 1491008400, 
                      1491012000, 1491026400, 1491033600, 
                      1491037200, 1491040800, 1491058800, 
                      1491062400, 1491066000, 1491069600, 
                      1491073200, 1491076800, 1491109200, 
                      1491112800, 1491120000, 1491123600, 
                      1491156000, 1491159600), 
                    tzone = "US/Mountain", 
                    tclass = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), 
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), 
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), 
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
  .indexTZ = "US/Mountain", 
  tzone = "US/Mountain", 
  .CLASS = "double", 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, "count"))

require("forecast")
library(highcharter)
library(xts)

t.arima <- auto.arima(t)
x <- forecast(t.arima, level = c(95, 80))

# Problem 

## Time from 'forecast'
time.x <- time(x$mean) # ts variable
time.x # see that frequency = 0.000277777777777778

## Original time
time.t <- time(t) # POSIXct variable, use as.ts to see frequency
as.ts(time.t) # frequency = 1

## Try to transform back to formatted date
as.POSIXct(as.double(time.t), tz = "US/Mountain", origin = "1970-01-01")
as.POSIXct(as.double(time.x), tz = "US/Mountain", origin = "1970-01-01")

#--------------------------------------------------------#

# SOLUTION 1
t.tmp <- ts(t, start=1, end = length(t))
t.arima.1 <- auto.arima(t.tmp)
x.1 <- forecast(t.arima.1, level = c(95, 80))

highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.1) %>%
  hc_add_series(x.1$x, name = "Original") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.1$fitted, name = "Fitted")

#------------------------------------------------------#

# SOLUTION 2 - With correct dates but wrong plot

## Create new forecast variable
x.2 <- forecast(t.arima.1, level = c(95, 80))

## Take forecast length
forecast.length <- length(time.x)

### Create New Forecast dates (HOUR)
### Since I don't know the exact forecast times, I'll add one HOUR
### for each obs starting from the last date in the original dataset 

last.date <- time.t[length(time.t)]

new.forecast.time.hour <- as.POSIXct(last.date) + c((1:forecast.length)*3600)

## Insert date back

x.2$mean  <- xts(x.1$mean, order.by = new.forecast.time.hour)
x.2$lower <- xts(x.1$lower, order.by = new.forecast.time.hour)
x.2$upper <- xts(x.1$upper, order.by = new.forecast.time.hour)

### Original Data
x.2$x <- xts(x.1$x, order.by = time.t)

### Fitted
x.2$fitted <- xts(x.1$fitted, order.by = time.t)

# Plot forecasts with correct date

highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.2) %>%
  hc_add_series(x.2$x, name = "Original") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.2$fitted, name = "Fitted") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')

#------------------------------------------------------#

# SOLUTION 3 - Correct plot but only for daily forecasts

## Create new forecast variable
x.3 <- forecast(t.arima.1, level = c(95, 80))

## Take forecast length
forecast.length <- length(time.x)

### Create New Forecast dates (DAY)
### Since I don't know the exact forecast times, I'll add one DAY
### for each obs starting from the last date in the original dataset 

last.date <- time.t[length(time.t)]

new.forecast.time.day <- as.POSIXct(last.date) + c((1:forecast.length)*3600*24)
## Add change from as.POSIXct to as.Date
new.forecast.time.day <- as.Date(new.forecast.time.day)

## Insert date back

x.3$mean  <- xts(x.1$mean, order.by = new.forecast.time.day)
x.3$lower <- xts(x.1$lower, order.by = new.forecast.time.day)
x.3$upper <- xts(x.1$upper, order.by = new.forecast.time.day)

### Original Data
x.3$x <- xts(x.1$x, order.by = time.t)

### Fitted
x.3$fitted <- xts(x.1$fitted, order.by = time.t)

# Plot forecasts with correct date

highchart(type = 'stock') %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.3) %>%
  hc_add_series(x.3$x, name = "Original") %>% 
  hc_add_series(x.3$fitted, name = "Fitted") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime')
```

**One other thing**: the fitted values on my plots differ from the fitted values on jbkunst's plot because he used `forecast` directly on `t`, not on `t.arima` (just a typo, I believe). This way, my forecasts are based on an Arima model, while his are based on an ETS model.